# Move Folders (including files) to new parent folder by year

Tags: windows, image, directory, organization

I tried RoboBasket3 but it did not do the job. I have searched through various tools but none seem to do the job.

I have a Pictures folder with 100 GB of data, 525 sub-folders and 25K+ files in the 525 sub-folders. Each of the 525 sub-folders are named based on the content of files e.g. 'Beach Visit 2010' or 'John Wedding'.

I want to recursively scan all files in each of the 525 folders, read the picture taken year and if all files in the folder are in 1 year move the folder to a parent folder for that year.

e.g.  John Wedding has 100 pictures all of which were taken in Oct 2010. So I want to move the John Wedding folder to a new parent folder called 2010. If a second folder also has files for 2010 then that folder should also be moved to the 2010 year folder (without removing the John Wedding folder from the folder)

I included an example of the current and new organized view I am looking to get.

How can this be achieved via a tool or java code? I am on windows 7.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you were to import all the photos to an iPhoto library then it would sort them by year, day, and month, while still keeping their event names from the folders when imported.

Just noticed you are on Windows 7.

I suspect Photoshop has a simular database but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't have iPhoto or Photoshop. Just want to organize this on my hard drive.